# How can I format date to string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

How can i format date in JS given in this format: Mon Jan 08 1996 00:00:00 GMT+0100  to string like this: "1996-01-06T23:00:00.000Z" ?

Comment: Maybe look(google) at `moment.js`. Be aware that your question might be voted down because it doesn't show any effort on your side.

Comment: There 's absolutely no need for a library for doing this.

Comment: There are [many, many duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date+string), please do a search and write some code before asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var str = "Mon Jan 08 1996 00:00:00 GMT+0100";

var date = new Date(str);

console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Make the string a date object, then convert it to ISO format. That's all there is.

Answer (score 1):

use the following :

```
var event = new Date('Mon Jan 08 1996 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
console.log(event.toISOString());
```

Answer (score -2):

1. First convert Mon Jan 08 1996 00:00:00 GMT+0100 to Date using new Date() function.
2. Second convert the new date into ISO format using toISO() function.